# Laravel - Jquery Dynamic Drop Down gives error 500 internal server error

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, ajaxform

I am trying to fetch the records on the second dropbox based on value selected in the first dropbox. My value in the first dropbox are loading, but when I select a random value, I dont get any values in the second value. I checked my console in the browser and I get the error showing (500 internal server error).

However, when this runned on the local host, it is working absolutely fine. This error occurs **only When Running On Live Server**

I have a master side bar file, that contains this form. and the ajax code is

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

     $('.dynamic').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() != '')
      {
       var select = $(this).attr("id");
       var value = $(this).val();
       var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
       var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
       $.ajax({
          url:"{{ route('pagescontroller.fetch') }}",
        method:"POST",
        data:{select:select, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent},
        success:function(result)
        {
         $('#'+dependent).html(result);
        }

       })
      }
     });
)};
```

my code in the controller:-

```
public function index(){
  $pc = $this->getPostcodes();
  $cl = $this->carFetch();
  return view('home')->with('postcodes', $pc)->with('carLists', $cl);
 }

public function getPostcodes(){
     $postcodes =  DB::table('postcodes')
              ->get();

            return $postcodes;
}

public function carFetch(){
    $carLists = DB::table('carlists')
            ->groupBy('Make')
            ->get();
            return $carLists;
}


      function fetch(Request $request)
      {
       $select = $request->get('select');
       $value = $request->get('value');
       $dependent = $request->get('dependent');
       $data = DB::table('carLists')
         ->where($select, $value)
         ->groupBy($dependent)
         ->get();
       $output = '<option value="">Select '.ucfirst($dependent).'</option>';
       foreach($data as $row)
       {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row->$dependent.'">'.$row->$dependent.'</option>';
       }
       echo $output;
      }
```

And my Routes:-

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index')
Route::post('sidebar/fetch', 'PagesController@fetch')->name('pagescontroller.fetch');
```

Not sure how its working on the localhost and not on the live server.

error screenshot:-
[image]

Comment: Please check the laravel log within your `storage/logs` folder it might give you more details on the error.

Comment: if you are using windows server...try checking connection string

Comment: @nakov I checked the log folder, and there are no files or error files that needed to check the logs

Comment: can you show the post params by clicking the post request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 500 error means that you have an error in your controller, put this into your JavaScript code:

```
...
success:function(result)
{
    $('#'+dependent).html(result);
},
error: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
...
```

So, you can read the error in the console and post an image in comments to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

```
DB::table('carlists')
 (or)
DB::table('carLists')
```

In carFetch your are using table name as carlists

but in fetch you are using table name as carLists

Linux server are case sensitive :)

```
$request->get('select');
```

to

```
$request->input('select');
```

Comment: I am using  a variable $cl and have named it as carList`->with('carLists', $cl);` to fetch the records on the view.  in the view i have:  `@foreach($carLists as $carMake)
    <option value="{{$carMake->Make}}">{{$carMake->Make}} </option>
    @endforeach`. My databae table is known as carList. Issue is its working fine on localhost but not working on live server

Comment: Yes, the index (home.blade.php) is loading fine. First Dropdown box is also working fine, but when i select the second drop down box, its empty.

Comment: yes i have, its in the code ` $carLists = DB::table('carlists')` instead $data i have used $carList. return the records, then sending it to another function (index) in a variable and returning it to the view . Its working fine on **Localhost** but not on the _live Server_

Comment: You are calling fetch() function through ajax call it will send response u can see it in console by pressing f12 under network tab...  what is you error in console

Comment: the error in the console is 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: this error comes when I select the value of first drop down box

Comment: And I just ran the site on localhost to see if its getting any error, and it is working like a charm. No error whatsoever...

Answer (score 1):

**You need to check .htaccess file.** any syntax errors will cause a 500 Internal Server Error message to be displayed. To confirm whether a misconfiguration .htaccess is the cause of the 500 Internal Server error, either remove or rename the .htaccess file temporarily and check.

Comment: I am sure the .htaccess file is fine. because, through my cPanel, I downloaded and Instal the package. all my other routes are working fine The 500 error,  showing when the action triggers on the first drop down box.

Comment: $select = $request->post('select');
 $value = $request->post('value');
$dependent = $request->post('dependent');

Not sure but try with this..

Comment: i tried changing the from get to post and its still not working. Error now i got is **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: Can you please share what is the problem (what you seen in **console.log(result)** ) ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur help, but I figured out the problem. it was silly mistake. Case sensitive as mentioned by @shibon earlier